# How to add JavaScript framework in rails app without adding gems?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I just want to know how to include frameworks like angularjs, polymer js, bootstrap.... Into rails app without adding corresponding gems. Reason is the gems that are available are changing and some of them are given up. So instead of gem I want to download the library files given by the vendor directly. How to add them into rails app?

Comment: It seems as simple as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22297700/ruby-on-rails-4-how-to-include-javascript-files-in-rails-web-application but you probably should read http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/javascript_include_tag and http://railsapps.github.io/rails-javascript-include-external.html if you'd like to do this right

Answer (score 0):

You can download the framework source files/folders, add them to your vendor folder and require those. Thats essentially what those gems do. If you're looking for a more advanced approach you can look into setting up a package manager like gulp and use the direct npm packages